# Cannot access administrator user on PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop, installation

I cannot access the admin user of my laptop.
I have Windows 7 installed on it.
When i login to the admin user it stucks on "welcome" screen.

I am logged in as a guest user and trying to resolve this issue, but it's very difficult. The problem is that every solution i found, from microsoft or from other sites, requires to install or use a program that demands to run it as administrator.

To explain the story behind my problem, i accidentally remove the power supply while i had no battery on it. What i concluded, is that this unexpected shutdown of my laptop caused loss or corruption of some important system files. One solution for this is to format my laptop.

**My question is if there is any other way to resolve this issue rather than format.**

Comment: Do note that even if you do manage to fix this particular issue, there is no guarantee as to the integrity of other important system files, thus restoring from a backup or a format/reinstall would be the best options for such a situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The idea to re-create the profile.

## And transfer files to a new working profile.

1. Boot at Windows 7/8 CD/USB.
   [image: Windows 7 boot begin]

[image: Install dialog]

2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (run `cmd`)

[image: Run cmd at Windows boot CD]

3. Run `regedit`

[image: Run <code>regedit</code>]

4.1. Select `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

[image: Load hive dialog]

4.2. Load `SOFTWARE` hive.

[image: Load <code>SOFTWARE</code> hive]

4.3. Set name to load hive.

[image: Set name to load hive.]

5. Save and delete User registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ **< NAME >** \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

5.1. Registry right click menu, export:
[image]

5.1. Registry export  dialog:
[image: Registry export dialog]

5.2. Delete User registry key.
[image: Delete User registry key]

6. Rename User Folder.

   6.1. Run notepad:

[image: Run notepad Windows 7 boot CD]

6.2. Rename user account folder C:\Users\:

[image: Rename user account folder]

7. Unmount Registry hive.

[image: Unmount Registry hive.]

8. Reboot. Press "Yes".

[image: Reboot]

9. Load OS. Logon at user.
10. Create second administrative user. Logoff at user.
11. Copy files at second administrative user.
12. Logon from you user.

Comment: A short intro paragraph giving a brief overview of what one is about to do by following these instructions would make this a great answer.

Comment: @Twisty Good thinking. Try to make a brief description later. But, I want to hear the reaction of the author of the problem. Thanks! Update.

Comment: @STTR It seems like a very good working solution. Unfortunately, I didn't test your solution because I did something different. I posted it as a new answer as well. Thanks for the useful information!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your user profile is corrupted. Press f8 when you first boot the pc start in safe mode with networking.

Try and log in to the administrator account - you should have more luck. Then either do a system restore, or if you're more confident - check the registry to see if your profile's key has been renamed with a .bak extention.. If it has just remove it(the.bak extention, not the profile).

Comment: Another way to access system restore if you still cant log in: F8 on boot, enter safe mode with command prompt, type rstrui.exe and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1)Boot at Windows 7 CD

2)Choose to install Windows 7

3)Do not delete/format any partition. In this way, all your data,
   including administrator's data will be saved to a folder called
   "Windows. Old"

4)After installing the Windows, Windows. Old folder will be
   accessible.